# Passing a set as a parameter in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I am trying to create a method in python (and utilizing numpy) to take a matrix `A` and reduce it to reduced row echelon form using the Gaussian Elimination Method.

I've run into my first problem which is trying to pass a set as a parameter.

For example:`def gauss([A]):` gets me an error which was surprising to me. Why is this?

Also, the way I plan to construct matrices (maybe it's the only way?) in the program is as follows:

```
a = numpy.array([[1 ,2 ,3] , [4 ,5 ,6] , [7 ,8 ,9]])
```

So I would like to be able to pass this `a` into my method `gauss(a)`, and then have gauss do terrible things unto thy matrix

thank you

Comment: It looks like you should change your function declaration to **def gauss(A):**, and then cast **A** to a set inside the function **gauss**.

Comment: Actually there are a lot of ways to create arrays in numpy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html  Also be aware that in numpy matrices and arrays are different objects.

Answer (score 6):

JoshAdel is right (in the now dearly departed comment) that it's normally impossible to tell what's going on without some code and sample output, but in this case I think I know:

```
def gauss([A]):
```

is not valid Python syntax. When you're declaring a function, you can't surround the parameter names with brackets. Just use

```
def gauss(A):
```

And if you want to pass a matrix/array/nested list or whatever into the function, just do it!

```
gauss(a)
```

In the method you can then treat the parameter `A` as a matrix.

Comment: Deleted the comment just before you posted this because I realized the issue

Answer (score 4):

Some further information in case you are new to Python and function definitions in Python.

`[A]` (i.e `A` enclosed in square brackets) is the *literal expression* for *making* a list containing `A`. Just as `42` is the *literal expression* for "making" an integer 42, 'foobar' is the literal expression for "making" the string `foobar` etc.

So trying to define a function with `def gauss([A]): pass` wouldn't make sense just as trying to define a function like `def gauss(42): pass` woudn't make sense.

However `def gauss(a=20): pass` is whole another story. In this case it creates a function with argument `a` and *default value* of 20. As a side note, it is not recommended to define a function like `def gauss(a=[]): pass` because `[]` is *mutable* and will cause issues as a default argument.

As others have already suggested `def gauss(a): ...` will fix your errors.

Answer (score 2):

`def func(param):` is how you define a function. You don't "pass" anything during a function definition. Does this work?

```
def gauss(a):
    # do something with `a`

gauss([A])
```